# ¿Como poner dos tipografias diferentes en flutter?

Tags: flutter

Como puedo hacer un salto de linea en flutter y que en el mismo parafo halla dos tipografías diferentes...

Ejemplo:

```
child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "Regalate un momento,"
                    "Viví Carhué",

              ),
            ),
```

"Regalate un momento" sea una tipografia y "vivi carhue" otra...

Comment: En cuanto a la tipografía, puedes probar con algun identificador tipo [What the font](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)

Comment: @gbianchi what the font identifica fuentes en imagenes

Comment: @Excelente chicos gracias, Y la segunda duda que tengo como puedo solucinarlo?

Comment: Por favor, **1 pregunta por publicación**, o te arriesgas a cerrar por `demasiado amplia`. Puesto que el tema de la fuente se ha solucionado en los comentarios, por favor, [edit] la pregunta y elimina esa parte.

Comment: Ahí esta jajaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El widget RichText muestra texto que usa múltiples estilos diferentes. El texto a mostrar se describe utilizando un árbol de objetos TextSpan, cada uno de los cuales tiene un estilo asociado que se usa para ese subárbol. El texto puede dividirse en varias líneas o puede mostrarse en la misma línea dependiendo de las restricciones de diseño.

Aquí esta mi fuente
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html